# How to do logout with Parse Swift iOS 8 Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

How do I log out with Parse Swift iOS 8 Xcode 6.4?

Here's a screenshot.

I need to add the action for my button so that I can log out with Parse.

http://i.gyazo.com/905df0a5f4bf29e7dd1a2b44e0c35865.png

Please help.

Thanks,

Jamie Mathieson

Answer (score 2):

After you are log out you need to present the LoginView Controller or Sign up

```
PFUSer.logout()
let Login = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(Login, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: but you need to reset variables and also to delete tab bars (if have some) show/hide navigation bars....

Answer (score 0):

```
PFUser.logOutInBackground(block: { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                // Show whatever screen you want here

                let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as! Wizard
                self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }})
```